# Origin of water under the dam

Tags: phrases, expressions

I'm trying to find out the origin of "water under the dam."
Was it an expression used in the nineteen twenties and was it considered an Irish expression?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that one, except as a joking mash-up of *water **over the dam*** and *water **under the bridge***. Where did you see it?

Comment: Don't count your chickens before you come to it.

Comment: @Mitch I'd rather burn that bridge when we get to it.

Comment: @AC Too many cooks? Get out of the kitchen!

Answer (score 28):

It is a [malaphor](http://www.yourdictionary.com/malaphor) (mixed metaphor) and, according to the following source, a common one:

***[That’s water under the dam](https://malaphors.com/2013/03/06/thats-water-under-the-dam/)***:

> This is a commonly used malaphor,  blending two idioms – “water under the bridge” and “water over the dam” – that contain the same word (water) and have the same meaning (past and unchangeable events).   ***Add two words that both describe direction (over and under), and two structures that are in or over water (dams and bridges) and you get a subtle  mix-up.***

(Malaphors.com)

The expression is probably more commonly used in speaking, but here are a few usage examples in writing:

From "[How can I fix it?](https://books.google.it/books?id=KtQKu5lS_wkC&pg=PA37&dq=%22water%20under%20the%20dam%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiAstGVg8jVAhXBwBQKHY21BTMQ6AEIIjAB#v=onepage&q=%22water%20under%20the%20dam%22&f=false)" (2001):

> Jackson said that she did feel bad about making the accusation, ***but it was now water under the dam.***

From "[Devil's Waltz: an Alex Delaware Novel](https://books.google.it/books?id=A8-13jdidkAC&pg=PT190&dq=%22water%20under%20the%20dam%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiAstGVg8jVAhXBwBQKHY21BTMQ6AEIKzAD#v=onepage&q=%22water%20under%20the%20dam%22&f=false)" (2003):

> Staring at the sodden cloth with surprise and revulsion. She dropped it as if it were lice-ridden. “***Forget it,” she said. “Water under the dam.”***

Comment: oo, heads off to Malaphors.com

Comment: I think I'll be using the tag 'rare neologism' in one or two future responses.

Comment: Actually it's just an elision of "water under the dam bridge".

Answer (score 6):

I think this is an accidental mix of "[water under the bridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/water-under-the-bridge)" and "water over the dam", which is a less common variation of the former.

Answer (score 6):

The earliest form of the phrase is ***water has flowed under the bridge*** appearing in 1858 according to [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/226109?redirectedFrom=water%20over%20the%20dam#eid327732296).  They also suggest comparing it to the French expression "il passera bien de l'eau sous le pont", lit. ‘much water will pass under the bridge’ (1842 or earlier).

> **water under the bridge** (also over the dam, under the dyke, under the mill, etc.): used in various expressions referring to the passing
>   of time, or (in later use) to suggest that past events have been
>   forgotten or are not worth bringing up or discussing.

1858   J. Kavanagh Adèle II. xviii. 288   Ah! water has flowed under the bridge, as people say, since those days.

Comment: Whoops, malaphored the previous version of this comment...The [*American Heritage Idioms Dictionary* (via Dictionary.com)](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/water-over-the-dam) claims that *over the dam* is the older version, dating it to 1797. Unfortunately, the actual attestation is not given at the Dictionary.com entry. Which version actually came first, and whence, might make an interesting separate question.

Comment: *French*: I have never seen, as far as I remember, the French equivalent of "water under the bridge" used in a present or future tense; I've only seen it used in a past tense. [Wiktionary](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/de_l%E2%80%99eau_est_pass%C3%A9e_sous_les_ponts) seems to mention 2 past forms ("de l'eau est passee sous les ponts" and "de l'eau a coule sous les ponts") and 1 future form ("de l'eau passera sous les ponts"), so the future form seems to exist though it's at least uncommon according to my personal experience.